# Is there an appropriate optic for set membership?

Tags: haskell, set, haskell-lens, lenses

I’m using `Data.Set`s in deeply-nested heterogeneous data structures, and thought it would be helpful to create a `Prism` for set membership. Hence:

```hs
membership :: (Ord a) => a -> Prism' (Set a) (Set a)
membership a = prism (Set.insert a) g
  where g as = if Set.member a as
               then Right $ Set.delete a as
               else Left as
```

However, this fails the first prism law, `preview l (review l b) ≡ Just b`, in the case where `review l` inserts a member that is already present in `b`, viz., if `l` is the membership lens for `a`, and `b` is `{a}`, then `review l b` is also `{a}`, and `preview l (review l b)` is just the null set, rather than just `{a}` as the first prism law requires.

Is there a better optic for capturing set membership? I like being able to check membership and conditionally decompose the set into the matching and non-matching parts simultaneously. Additionally, having an optic to do this is appealing because, since it captures all the use-cases I have for working with `Set`s in other parts of my code, it enables me to remove my `import Data.Set` statements from the rest of my package, which often indicates successful abstraction to me.

Comment: Does `at`/`alterF` suit you? AFAIK that's kind of the "best" description of `Set` in terms of the optics vocabulary.

Comment: In particular, the requested decomposition `a -> Set a -> (Bool, Set a)` is just `alterF (, False)`, which should also be `flip at (, False)` or `\x -> at x %%~ (, False)`.

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten that Sets could be treated as Map-like containers, and therefore could be used with At. (Although, I’m not sure how one gets around the law ```ix k ≡ at k . traverse``` when Set is not Traversable, or even a Functor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`Contains`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#t:Contains) type class with a member:

```
contains :: Contains m => Index m -> Lens' m Bool
```

which when specialised to `Set` is

```
contains :: Ord a => a -> Lens' (Set a) Bool
```

It is probably a good exercise to think why it is a *lens* (and not a prism, as in your attempt).

Comment: My understanding is that ```contains``` is a lens, rather than a prism, because ```member (a :: a)``` is valid projection for all ```as :: Set a```.